# Determinant of matrices with entries $a_{i, j} = \operatorname{gcd}(i, j)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory, determinant

Suppose we have $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with $a_{i,j}={\rm gcd}(i,j)$. What is the determinant of $A$?

Comment: Did you bother to do some examples, say with $\;n=1,2,3,4,...\;$ ? Do you some educated guess? In short, what have you done so far?

Comment: It strikes me that this looks a lot like the matrix $a_{ij} = ij$, which would have rank $1$.  I would guess, then, that $A$ should have determinant $0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think the matrix is regular and its determinant, according to the examples I did and if I am *not* wrong, equals $\;n-2\;,\;\;n\ge3\;$ , and $\;1\;$ if $\;n=1,2\;$ .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This quantity is the so-called *Smith determinant* and turns out to be
$$\det A = \prod_{k = 1}^n \varphi(k),$$
where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. Smith's original paper is

> H. J. S. Smith, On the value of a certain arithmetical determinant, *Proc. London Math. Soc.* **7** (1875-1876), pp. 208-212.

but, despite its age, it is gated. A modern (and ungated) explanation, which exploits the LU decomposition, appears, e.g., in

> Antal Bege, [Hadamard product of GCD matrices](http://www.emis.de/journals/AUSM/C1-1/MATH1-4.PDF), *Acta Univ. Sapientiae*, Mathematica, 1, **1** (2009), pp. 43-49.

More references appear in [A001088](http://oeis.org/A001088), the OEIS entry for the sequence
$$1, 1, 2, 4, 16, 32, 192, 768, \ldots,$$
whose $n$th entry is the determinant $\det A$ of the $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: A typo - the product is over $\phi(i)$, not $\phi(n)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks, you're right of course. One should probably avoid $i$ anyway, since OP uses it to index matrix rows.

Answer (score 6):

The result is
$$
\det(A)=\prod_{k=1}^n\phi(k).
$$
see [here](http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=Determinant_with_gcd%28i,j%29_for_%28i,j%29th_entries).

Comment: This fits with what I did in some examples. Any hint as to the why?

Comment: Broken link, remove the final '='

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for fixing the broken link.

Comment: @DietrichBurde no problem. Good find!